# How to call WPF app in powershell after windows 7 logoff

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, powershell

I wonna call my wpf app after windows 7 has logoff. I wrote a powershell script that call my wpf app and wait until wpf app get close.
The code

```
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("D:\PowerShell\PsWpf.exe");
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo;
$p.Start();
$p.WaitForExit();
```

When i try to use this script as logoff script, configured in gpedit.msc under Windows Setting-->Scripts-->Logoff, then my computer get freeze, that means no reaction.

If i execute the script as usual, that mean right click on powershell file, then "Run then with Powershell", everything runs fine.

How to call my wpf app in powershell after windows logoff?

I know it is possible to use wpf in powershell, like

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore
Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase
[xml]$xaml = 
@"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PowerShell WPF" Height="244" Width="525" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Background="#58000000">
        <Label Content="Designed and Developed by Free Lancer" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="288,165,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )


$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

and use it as logoff script it works fine. My Problem is, i can't script in powershell only in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

From what I took away from your question in its current form (a little confusing to be honest), I think you're wanting to:

1. Initiate a process at the logoff event
2. Do so with Group Policy
3. Pause logoff until the script action and process complete

I'm scratching my head why you're using:

```
$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("D:\PowerShell\PsWpf.exe");
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo;
$p.Start();
$p.WaitForExit();
```

I'm wondering if this might be better:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Powershell\PsWpf.exe" -Wait
```

Using the `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` param will pause the script execution until the process "PsWpf.exe" ends.  Also, you might not be aware but GPO executes with the CMD shell not Powershell.  So to execute powershell commands from a CMD environment you need to encapsulate them like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Powershell\PsWpf.exe" -Wait}
```

If your computer is still hanging at shutdown/logoff it's because the program `PsWpf.exe` is not exiting.

Comment: i try this Start-Process -FilePath "D:\Powershell\PsWpf.exe" -Wait -WindowStyle Normal and the wpf window shows, but it does not wait until i finish the programm. The wpf window appears just only for one second and after the computer gets shutdown. But what i want is, the computer is not going to shutdown, until i finish the wpf programm.